# Does number of particle emitters effects performance?

Tags: libgdx

I have created 7 emitters all using the same image does it affect the performance on the android device because I am a bit confused that in github it's written to use the pool and I don't understand that we should use it when we have many "ParticleEffect" or "ParticleEmitter"?

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking. Absolutely anything can effect performance, depending on how much you have going on. A single particle effect can bring you down to 1 FPS if the particles are very big on the screen and there are more than a few of them. Pooling is used to cut down on memory allocations and garbage collector use, which both cause stutters, not continuous lower frame rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not do any performance tests here on my own, but let me cite the [libgdx wiki on that topic](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-ParticleEffects):

> Creating new ParticleEffects willy nilly? Great, now stop doing that
>   and use a Pool! Unfortunately garbage collection degrades the
>   performance of your game, especially on the mobile platforms, so you
>   want to avoid garbage at all costs. Use of the ParticleEffectPool
>   completely mitigates garbage generation as you will be reusing your
>   ParticleEffect when you are finished with them. No more wasted memory!
>   No more garbage collection

So the idea of pools is to reuse particle effects that use the same image instead of constantly deleting and creating new particle objects. This is a pattern known as [Object Pool](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/object-pool.html), which is quite common especially in game development:

> Intent: Improve performance and memory use by reusing objects from a fixed
>   pool instead of allocating and freeing them individually.